# Reading from binary file, BinaryReader get 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.' C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use BinaryWriter and BinaryReader to manage data in files. Obviously I can save data to file, but when I try get it, I still have got the System.IO.EndOfStreamException: 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.' This wasn't happened when I try use with simple strings, integer etc. But for the example below I get an exception.

_employees - this is the list with objects Employee, only IsEmployed is boolean, others are string

```
private static void SaveEmployee()
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("EixbpLGV70YuBlXMlFqg0g==.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(_employees.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < _employees.Count; i++)
                {
                    writer.Write($"{_employees[i].Name}");
                    writer.Write($"{_employees[i].LastName}");
                    writer.Write($"{_employees[i].Pesel}");
                    writer.Write($"{_employees[i].PhoneNumber}");
                    writer.Write($"{_employees[i].Post}");
                    writer.Write($"{_employees[i].IsEmployed}");
                }   
            }
        }
```

And method to read from file:

```
private static void ReadEmployee()
        {
            Employee employee;
            
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("EixbpLGV70YuBlXMlFqg0g==.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                int j = reader.ReadInt32();
                string name, lastName, pesel, phoneNumber, post;
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                {
                    name = reader.ReadString();
                    lastName = reader.ReadString();
                    pesel = reader.ReadString();
                    phoneNumber = reader.ReadString();
                    post = reader.ReadString();
                    employee = new Employee(name, lastName, pesel, phoneNumber, post);
                    employee.IsEmployed = reader.ReadBoolean();

                    _employees.Add(employee);
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It appears your `IsEmployed` Property is a `bool`, but you're writing a string that represents a `bool` (`"True"`, `"False"`), then you try to read back a `bool` with `employee.IsEmployed = reader.ReadBoolean();`. This will throw off the BinaryReader. You should store the bool value with `writer.Write(_employees[i].IsEmployed);` (also the other values) -- Why don't you use, e.g., JSON serialization instead? One command to serialize all, same to deserialize, hassle-free. -- The FileStream should also be declared with a `using` statement.

Comment: With *throw off the BinaryReader* I mean, it will try to read a `bool` (a byte: `00` or `01`), it will find the `T` of `"True"`, or the `F` of `"False"` (`> 0`, so always `true`), then it will try to find a string right after, from that position +1. It won't find the marker there; this will cause it to jump to the end of the Stream, reading beyond EOF.

Comment: Ugh, thank you very much. I remember that i tried something with that write and propably i forgot about this curly braces. Now it works. Thank you!